# Move Windows 7 to another drive on dual boot machine

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7, ssd

I have a dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 machine both using a 500 Gig SSD. I want to increase the space available to Windows 7 by adding another SSD. Since there seem to be some stories about Windows updates nuking other partitions on the drive it occupies (https://forum.level1techs.com/t/solved-windows10-anniversary-nuked-my-linux-partition-table/110271 , https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/partition-disappears-in-win-10-anniversary-update.html , https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/windows-10-update-messes-with-linux-partition/f3584285-72b7-4f4e-8e7b-5a8b0eadbb72), I thought it might be a better idea to move Windows 7 to its own SSD, separating the two OSs onto their own drives.

I copied my Windows 7 partition to the new SSD using GParted, but when I run "update-grub" from linux to add the new copy of Windows to the GRUB boot menu, it doesn't find the new copy, only the old one. It makes no difference whether the new SSD Windows partition is mounted or not.

What additional steps have I missed here? I only have a vague understanding of how a computer boots up.

Also, is this approach even the best one? If Windows 7 actually doesn't pose any risk to Linux (it's given me no problems for a couple of years), then simply using the new drive as a D: drive for Windows (and some additional space for Linux) would probably be a better idea.

EDIT: I've added a few links to stories of Windows 10 corrupting partition tables to back-up my rationale for moving Windows to its own drive. However, if Windows 7 poses no risk, please feel free to tell me my approach is unnecessary.

Comment: A simple copy to another drive will not create another operating OS. Simple copies will copy all of the files, but the copy will not set up the boot configuration so the 'copy' will not be seen as a working OS. The best way to do this is to do a new Windows 7 install on the new SSD and then copy over the files needed for your current setup (programs, documents, pics, etc). There will be some additional work to set up your desktop (prog. shortcuts).

Comment: If you want to add the full new SSD to Windows, don't do anything!  Just add it to the system and create a new drive letter under Windows and then move Windows Data over to that new drive.  (off-topic here, so leaving a comment instead of an answer)

Comment: @Craig  Although that would work, it seems a shame to go to all the effort of doing a reinstall just to obtain a bootable installation. Surely there is a more direct way of making a clone bootable?

Comment: @Fabby This is very easy to do, but I'm exploring the possibility of moving all of Windows to its own drive because of some reports of Windows corrupting partition tables during updates. Microsoft themselves recommend "other operating systems" go on separate drives (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/windows-10-update-messes-with-linux-partition/f3584285-72b7-4f4e-8e7b-5a8b0eadbb72)  However, if there is no risk of Windows corrupting Linux, I will just add the drive as a data drive and not move Windows. Is this actually a risk with Windows 7?

Comment: Windows corrupting other OSes will happen regardless of whether it has its own boot drive or not. That's why we have [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: If you do an image copy, you will normally get duplicate UUIDs which is not allowed. The issue of Windows corrupting partition table, is with the old MBR and Windows rewriting the partition table with major update (like to Windows 10) & not seeing or including any Linux partitions in partition table update. You can backup partition table and easily restore it or use testdisk. Data is still there, just not partition table entry. Newer UEFI systems with gpt do not seem to have that issue.