# Grub: How to config boot windows after move Windows to another Drive

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

As the title, I have one PC with Windows 10 & Ubuntu 20.041. I had installed new Windows OS to new Drive on my PC, and delete the old once. After that, I realize that Bios, Grub still point to old Drive. That is inconvenience when I want to boot to Windows. Here is the information of the drive. The new drive is **sdc**, **sda** is Ubuntu home.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 232.91 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 850 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F82E1268-F300-4AD2-9BF3-606A39597B64

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 488396799 487346176 232.4G Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/sdc: 232.91 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 860 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7c95812f

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *     2048 488394751 488392704 232.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

I search around and try with update-grub but no luck.

```
sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-54-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-54-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-53-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-53-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-52-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
```

I found similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115123/move-windows-7-to-another-drive-on-dual-boot-machine) but have no answer yet.
Do you have any idea how to correct the boot to new windows drive?
Thanks

Comment: seal2002 You have a UEFI system set-up for Ubuntu. In UEFI mode your PC will not read the Windows disk, because it's set up for legacy BIOS with an MBR boot (in dos format). You need to [convert your Windows drive to a GPT format](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-convert-mbr-disk-gpt-move-bios-uefi-windows-10) for it to be read.

Comment: Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives since 2012 and release of Windows 8. Users could use the old BIOS install, but that was more for large customers with many systems to allow similar configuration. You also have to convert drive to gpt as Windows in UEFI mode only installs to gpt partitioned drives. And how you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs.

Comment: Thank you @PaulBenson and oldfred, I totally forget about UEFI, when I installed Windows OS to new drive, I format with default, I don't remember that having an option format with GPT. Follow the link convert windows driver to a GPT format. My ubuntu can see the driver, and update-grub is successful. Thanks again.